# Insert an element into the end of every list

Tags: list-manipulation

I have made a list partition and would like to insert an Element X into the end of every partition.

> **Input:** `{1,2,3,4,5},{6,7,8,9,10},{11,12,13,14,15}...{91,92,93,94,95,X}`
>
> **Output:**`{1,2,3,4,5,X},{6,7,8,9,10,X},{11,12,13,14,15,X}...{91,92,93,94,95,X}`

I have looked at the command `Insert`, but I don't know what to do, when there is so many lists.

I have tried something like: `Insert[[#] &, "X", Last[#] &]`

Answer (score 9):

Some more options:

[`ArrayPad`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ArrayPad.html):

```
ArrayPad[list, {{0, 0}, {0, 1}}, "X"]
```

[`Append`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Append.html) in operator form:

```
Append["X"] /@ list
```

Using [`Function`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Function.html) and [`Apply`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Apply.html):

```
{##, "X"} & @@@ list
```

With [`Replace`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Replace.html):

```
Replace[list, {x__} :> {x, "X"}, 1]
```

Comment: Probably the fastest of all. +1.

Answer (score 5):

`Append` would work.

```
list = {{7, 5, 8, 3, 4}, {4, 8, 9, 7, 3}, {7, 0, 1, 4, 6},
 {3, 0, 4, 7, 9}, {5, 1, 2, 7, 4}};
Append[#, "X"] & /@ list

(* {{7, 5, 8, 3, 4, "X"}, {4, 8, 9, 7, 3, "X"}, {7, 0, 1, 4, 6, "X"},
 {3, 0, 4, 7, 9, "X"}, {5, 1, 2, 7, 4, "X"}} *)
```

Answer (score 4):

```
list = {{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, {6, 7, 8, 9, 10}, {11, 12, 13, 14, 15}};

 Flatten /@ Thread[List[list, X]]
```

> {{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, X}, {6, 7, 8, 9, 10, X}, {11, 12, 13, 14, 15, X}}

Comment: Your `MapAt` code overwrites the last element of each list rather than adding a new one.

Answer (score 4):

Another solution using `ConstantArray` and `Transpose`

```
list = {{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, {6, 7, 8, 9, 10}, {11, 12, 13, 14, 15}};
Flatten /@ Transpose[{list, ConstantArray[X, Length@list]}]
```

> {{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, X}, {6, 7, 8, 9, 10, X}, {11, 12, 13, 14, 15, X}}

Answer (score 3):

```
SeedRandom[12]
list = RandomInteger[10, {4, 5}]
Join[#, {"x"}] & /@ list

(*Out:
{{2, 4, 0, 10, 1}, {9, 7, 3, 1, 10}, {7, 0, 9, 5, 4}, {6, 7, 2, 8, 5}}
{{2, 4, 0, 10, 1, "x"}, {9, 7, 3, 1, 10, "x"}, {7, 0, 9, 5, 4, "x"}, {6, 7, 2, 8, 5, "x"}}
*)
```

Comment: Very slow for very large lists.

Answer (score 3):

If `lists` form a regular array (good for packed arrays):

```
lists=Partition[Range[15], 5];
PadRight[lists, {Automatic, 1 + Length@First@lists}, x]
(*  {{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, x}, {6, 7, 8, 9, 10, x}, {11, 12, 13, 14, 15, x}}  *)
```

---

Or:

```
Append[#, "X"] & /@ lists
```

Answer (score 3):

Using `Insert` you can do as follows

```
list = {{4, 7, 8, 8, 5}, {7, 2, 9, 7, 0}, {2, 7, 1, 6, 5}, {6, 6, 7, 
4, 3}};

Insert[#, x, Length@# + 1] & /@ list

(*{{4, 7, 8, 8, 5, x}, {7, 2, 9, 7, 0, x}, {2, 7, 1, 6, 5, x}, {6, 6, 7,
 4, 3, x}}*)
```

Comment: Very slow for very large lists.

Answer (score 0):

A simple case of patterns,

`Partition[Range[20], 4] //. {s___Integer} :> {s, "x"}`

```
{{1, 2, 3, 4, "x"}, {5, 6, 7, 8, "x"}, {9, 10, 11, 12, "x"}, {13, 14, 
  15, 16, "x"}, {17, 18, 19, 20, "x"}}
```